# The Activity image field is required in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter-3

I'm trying to upload image in my code project. In the image field I'm getting

> "The Activity image field is required."

The below code is my Activity_controller

```
public function create_activity(){
//...Upload the image
//... path to upload image
  $config['upload_path'] = './assets/images/uploads'; // The path to upload the image
  $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png|pdf|doc';
  $config['max_size'] = '2048';
  $config['max_width'] = '500';
  $config['max_height'] = '500';

  $this->load->library('upload',$config);

  if(!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    $activity_image = 'noimage.jpg';
  } else {
    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    $activity_image = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
  }

  $this->activity_model->save_activity($activity_image);
  redirect('activity_controller');
}
```

Activity model, insert activity in the database    Here is only the function to insert data in the database.

```
public function save_activity($activity_image){
//... code to insert others data in the database

  'activity_image' => $activity_image
                            );
                            return $this->db->insert('activity', $data);
                        }
```

Below code is create_activities.php file in the view folder:

```
                    <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
                    <?php echo form_open_multipart('activity_controller/create_activity');  ?>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Upload image</label>
                        <input name="userfile" type="file">
                        </div>
```

I have loaded the model in the autoload.php file.
I also used `<input name="activity_image type="file">`

"image_name" is the name of the field in the database table

Please someone can help me to solve this problem? I will appreciate your help

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to add **(enctype="multipart/form-data")** in your view file in form Tag.

Here, Usen this code. I hope this one is help full to you.

```
<form action="/action_page_binary.asp" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  First name: <input type="file" name="name"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```